# Split Just the first token of a string in C

Tags: c, strtok

I'm having trouble splitting just the first word of a string in C.

I've already tried `strtok()` and read some related questions here, but nothing worked as I expected.

For example the input:

```
USA;Soccer;Baseball;NBA
```

I want as output:

```
Soccer;Baseball;NBA
```

Comment: `strtok` will split out all the parts of the string, so it will "return" `"USA"`, `"Soccer"`, `"Baseball"`, `"NBA"` and `NULL`.

Comment: Please show the code. @che Whut?

Comment: @user58697 see below

Comment: ***Show Code***

Answer (score 3):

You can try this
[strstr manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
        char *a = "USA;Soccer;Baseball;NBA";
        //char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
        char *b = strstr(a, ";");
        if((b != NULL))
            printf("%s\n",b+1);
        return 0;
}
```

OR this:

[strchr manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
            char *a = "USA;Soccer;Baseball;NBA";
            //char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
            char *b = strchr(a, ';');
            if((b != NULL))
                printf("%s\n",b+1);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You need to include <string.h> to guaranteed that strxxx() function prototypes will be included.  That's also one of the headers guaranteed to define NULL. (<stdio.h> is not guaranteed to define NULL, btw)

Comment: the example is wrong... in the case of a string with several `;` (e.g. `"USA;;;;Soccer; BaseBall;NBA;"`, you'll get incorrect output).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly related: [`strtok()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) will split string into a sequence of tokens, which could be used if you needed to get all the parts of the original string, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
        char line[] = "USA;Soccer;Baseball;NBA";

        char * cur;
        for (cur = strtok(line, ";"); cur != NULL; cur = strtok(NULL, ";")) {
                printf("- %s\n", cur);
        }
}
```

Note that:

- `strtok` holds some internal state, so you cannot nest two such loops within one another (`strtok_r` avoids this problem)
- `strtok` changes the original string, so if you need it afterwards you need to make a copy

Answer (score 0):

If you do not allow certain characters in your string, you could still use `strtok`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char input[] = "USA;Soccer;Baseball;NBA";
    char *skip   = strtok(input, ";");
    char *output = strtok(NULL, "?"); // Or any other character not allowed in the string.
    if(output != NULL)
        printf("%s\n",output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can use `strtok(NULL, ""); ` instead of trusting a non allowed character.